# What is this particular type of shortcut for javascript in vscode called? (see image) And/Or more importantly: Where to see a full list?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would like to have a list of these shortcuts, that are only a few characters long, but I don't know what they are called or where they come from.

[image: Screenshot of ifelse-shortcut in vscode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [code snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets). You can see a list of all of the built-in JS ones if you navigate to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets\javascript.json
```

or to a similar path.

You can also write your own snippets, which may be located at a path similar to

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets\javascript.json
```

Comment: For anyone else interested, I accidentally discovered that you can view a list of snippets by hitting `⌃Space` and scroll down. Also didn't know that in Mac file search, application files don't show up. So you have to go there manually ... /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/javascript/snippets/javascript.json